# Can not assign property of nested model using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model which has inside another model as:

```
  public class DesignListViewModel
    {
        public IList<DesignViewModel> DesignList { get; set; } = new List<DesignViewModel>();
    }
```

So I want to assign a property inside that DesignViewModel in my controller using LINQ as:

```
  var rModel = await _designService.Get(model); //rModel equals to DesignListViewModel

  //Trying to assign column duedate 
  rModel.DesignList.Select(design => design.DueDate).FirstOrDefault() = new DateTime();
```

But it throws an error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
> indexer

How can I access that column as a variable to assign the new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to assign property/field of some class instance (assuming `DesignViewModel` is a class) you need to aquire the instance and specify what you are trying to set. For example:

```cs
rModel.DesignList.First().DueDate = new DateTime();
```

Or via variable:

```cs
var first = rModel.DesignList.First();
first.DueDate = new DateTime();
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` in this case does not make much sense cause for empty list it will result in `null` with following code producing `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: `DateTime` is non-nullable, if the list is empty `FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(DateTime)` -> `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: @BurnsBA thank you. I know that. It's a pity you can't set it so the value stored in the original collection is modified =)